# How do I make sure an enemy captain stays dead after I have defeated him?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I just tried to kill a captain that was already difficult enough, and suddenly another captain appears that I already had killed. He taunts me, telling me that I should have made sure to kill him and swears revenge.

The appearance of that guy made an already far too hard fight impossible, and I simply ran away.

I'd really like for the captains I defeat to stay dead, how can I make sure of that?

Answer (score 11):

To make sure that they stay dead, you need to behead them.

At least that's what the [IGN Wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor/The_Nemesis_System) tells me:

> Death in the Nemesis System
>
> Death is not the end in the Nemesis System: Not for Talion, and not
>   always for the Uruks either. Whenever you kill a Captain or Warchief
>   in Sauron's Army, **there is a chance that they will survive the
>   apparent killing blow. This can only happen if the Uruk in question
>   was not beheaded in the finishing blow**. Any Uruks that are lying down
>   dead in the army page may come back and hunt Talion for revenge. After
>   encountering them in the wild, they will reappear in the army page,
>   now on their feet and sporting new scars based on their previous
>   encounter. Some Uruks may even gain Strengths and Weaknesses depending
>   on what happened to them.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but *how* do I behead a captain? Does the sword through the face thing I do after interrogating an orc count as beheading?

Comment: Haven't played the game yet, but I saw some videos, where a finisher is a beheading. I also saw another video, where a captain comes back - this one was finished with the "sword-through-face". So, my deduction: You have to sever the head from the rest of the body (behead the guy).

Comment: @Uruk-Hai You can use the Executions moves once you unlocked them. I have not played too much yet (at the second warchief now) but there must be more fatal abilities that can permanently kill captains.

Comment: @Uruk-Hai I think it is just random luck... depends which move you get.

Comment: I'm sure they wouldn't base the permanent death of a captain on whether you was lucky enough to get a finisher that beheaded them. I have racked up quite a few hours on this amazing game now and most of it was just exploring and taking out captains because it is fun as hell. There have been plenty of instances where I am sure they were beheaded but returned anyway, also there are captains that have remained dead after just been slashed or shot to death. There was one captain who I had to kill 4 times before he stayed dead, by the end he had a black bag over his head. Pretty funny actually.

Comment: @SimonM - Well, that's what I found. It's entirely possible that beheading does not permanently kill a captain. We'll have to wait and see what comes up.

Comment: @5pike I have heard a random orc brag about how if i chopped off his head he would put it back on and continue the fight. Least, i hope he said head, since that would make this totally valid

Answer (score 9):

Aside from beheading, making a Uruk captain's head explode will also make them stay dead after killing them (required skill: Wraith Finisher). With this skill, enemies that are killed by draining or Flurry Kill (on stunned enemies) will have their heads explode.

Also, you can [feed a Uruk captain to a Graug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3QD4.jpg) (required skill to mount Graugs: Graug Hunter), which has the same effect of making an enemy stay dead.

Note that some enemy captains can't be beheaded / head-exploded by execution (e.g. those with the 'Combat Master' trait). In that case, you would have to make do with a drain head explosion (if they can be grabbed, grab them and keep on draining them until dead), Lethal Shadow Strike skill (if they aren't invulnerable to ranged attacks) or feeding them to a Graug.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend actually planning the attack. Learn his weaknesses and strengths. If it doesn't show, experiment. And once you find his Achilles heel, try going one on one to enjoy it. Wraith Stun a particular Uruk and continually Flurry him, but never reach the end. If you have that ability to use 2 Melee Executions at once, stop Flurrying the particular Uruk and silmuntaniously attack 2 other unsuspecting Uruks. Or if you have a big combo going on, use a Wraith Flash, I think thats what it's called where you unleash a blue wave along the ground. It takes care of a lot of Uruks. Then after that, enjoy your one on one with the Captain. If there are multiple Captains, never let your guard down and use your brain before getting the glory. As for beheading, for me, throwing them off cliffs work as well but beheading was always the best.