# How can I ensure that I cut my nemeses' heads off?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I understand that I need to cut off the head of a Uruk captain to [make sure they stay dead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185810/how-do-i-make-sure-an-enemy-captain-stays-dead-after-i-have-defeated-him), but I don't know how to do this reliably. Once in a while I get lucky and a finishing move decapitates the enemy, but other times I simply run them through and they're up again and chasing after me the next day.

Is there any way to guarantee that a finishing move is a beheading?

Comment: I havent played Mordor enough to be sure (only watched Let's Plays) but it looked to me like that was in the skill tree?

Comment: If it is, I haven't seen it as of Tier 3 (unless it's cleverly disguised).

Comment: Now I don't know this for sure, but I think an Uruk with the combat finisher weakness will be beheaded by the execute finisher. I've only beheaded 2 Captains and both of them were with the combat finisher weakness.

Comment: If you could get the skill to make their head explode on a drain/flurry kill, that might work.

Comment: @Djorge - I got those skills, but it doesn't work on nemeses.

Comment: The only way to do it I guess is to brand them and then use detonate (did this last night). But once you brand them they're not a threat anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way where, when executed properly, you can ensure you a 100% decapitation.

You have to unlock the Wraith Finisher Skill, that garantees you a decapitation (well, a head explosion...) after the entire combo.

To do that, tap E (on PC) to stun your victim, and then spam Right Click (normal attack).

Note that the finisher will only activate if your commander is low health, while always works on normal Uruks.

Sadly using the normal finisher, there's nothing that can garantee you a 100% decapitation.

Comment: This finisher never worked for me, when I used them on commanders. Will test it again.

Comment: It's not easy to pull it off. The captain/commander needs to be low health enough. I usually hit them with normal attacks, until they are low enough to try the wraith combo.

Comment: Some Uruk's are immune to the wraith stuns and also have combat mastery which makes them immune to the flurry attacks after the stun. So this can't be used all the time tho

Comment: @Lyrion didn't know that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Couldn't you just get them low enough to grab them, interrogate them, then kill them afterward? I don't usually kill captains now that I have brand but I usually kill anybody else that I interrogate, and it does the "shove-sword-in-face-pull-out-and-off-with-yer-head" animation

Comment: Brand & Dispatch!  It's like a 4th of July finale.

Answer (score 2):

This is meant to be a percentage chance. The game was never meant to give you this option, since you could annihilate the whole army incredibly quickly. It's just a random event to help you stay on top of your game, without giving you exploitative powers.

**TL;DR** You can't, cause the game only wants it to be the only thing that *can*

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 skills in the game that will let you decap 100% of the time:

- Wraith finisher
- Shadow strike
- Dispatch